# C# SQL Connection string " can't find the table "

Tags: c#, sql

Currently I'm working on a project that generates files....().
Everything seems to work well. I can connect to the database and my methods of reading and writing are working, too, but I can't find the table. I have an error:

> $exception    {"Invalid object name 'T_SAL'."} System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

I don't know if the problem is with my connection string or something else! 
Is there anyone that can help me with this, please?

My methods' code:

//SQL connection Methods**

```
     public static SqlConnection OpenSql(bool Authentification, string   SQL_LOGIN, string SQL_PASSWORD, string SQL_SERVER, string BASE_CONSOLE) 

  {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            String Securité;

            if (Authentification)
            {
                Securité = "Integrated Security = true";
            }
            else
    {Securité = "User Id =" + SQL_LOGIN + ";" + "Password =" + SQL_PASSWORD;}
       conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + SQL_SERVER + ";Initial Catalog=" + BASE_CONSOLE + ";" + Securité + ";";

            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            return null;
        }
```

// Generation :

```
private void Gen_f_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = Methodes.OpenSql(Authentification.Checked, SQL_SERVER.Text, BASE_CONSOLE.Text, SQL_LOGIN.Text, SQL_PASSWORD.Text );
        if (conn == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connexion impossible");
            return;
        }


        try
        {

            //traitement du fichier des salaeiés                
            var lines = Methodes.lecture(fp_text.Text);
            foreach (var ligne in lines)
            {
                string[] cols = ligne.Split(char.Parse(";"));                    
                string Matricule = cols[0];

                if (Matricule != "" && MatriculeExiste(conn, Matricule) == false)
                {
                    string ligneSorties = "";

                    ligneSorties = ligneSorties + cols[0] + ";";


                    Methodes.Ecriture(ligneSorties, "fp_sorties.'Text'", true);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

        }
    }




    private bool MatriculeExiste(SqlConnection conn, string Matricule)

         {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MatriculeSalarie FROM [T_SAL] WHERE MatriculeSalarie='" + Matricule + "'", conn);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the table `T_SAL` in your database?

Comment: Does the user you are using have access/permissions to that table?

Comment: Did you try to view the `inner exception` in the debugger. it can give you more insight on the problem awaken

Comment: It could be many things. One of them could be that the table is not part of the dbo schema, but of another one which you didn't specify, but this is just a guess. Generally, it is good practice to use `schema.objectName` when using database objects. Maybe you are connecting to the wrong database? Or maybe your user does not have rights to query this table.

Comment: @JoshAdams Yes, actualy i'm using Windows authentification i don't if the problem is related to this !!

Comment: @Stefan Yes the table existe in my data base

Comment: @Sion.D.P thanks i will try this i will see if it can help me

Comment: @RigertaDemiri everything is good with the connection to the databasse i virefied everything the  only problem that i have is why it can finde the table !

Comment: @Bearcat9425 this is my SQL query:                                                                                                                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT MatriculeSalarie FROM [T_SAL] WHERE MatriculeSalarie='" + Matricule + "'", conn);

Comment: Why don't you try to preempt your table in your query by [Database].[Schema].[Table] `SELECT MatriculeSalarie FROM [YOUR_DB].[YOUR_SCHEMA].[T_SAL]`

Comment: Did you try to remove the square brackets [ ] from the  table name?

Comment: I saw the query after I posted that, apparently I forgot how to scroll, and feeding off @JaimeDrq 's comment have you tried a full qualified table name like he suggests.  Also parameterized queries,  please research those and implement just an FYI.

Comment: Also in debug mode inspect your BASE_CONSOLE value and make sure its the right database name.

Comment: @JaimeDrq Thanks a lot your answer did help :-D

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Thank you for your answers to, you gave some good tips

Comment: thak you for all your answers i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the order of parameters that you pass to `OpenSql` method:

```
 public static SqlConnection OpenSql(bool Authentification, string   SQL_LOGIN, string SQL_PASSWORD, string SQL_SERVER, string BASE_CONSOLE)
```

This is how you call it:

```
    SqlConnection conn = Methodes.OpenSql(Authentification.Checked, SQL_SERVER.Text, BASE_CONSOLE.Text, SQL_LOGIN.Text, SQL_PASSWORD.Text );
```

There is definitely some mismatch with the order of parameters, your declaration expects `SQL_Login, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_SERVER, BASE_CONSOLE` and you are passing `SQL_SERVER, BASE_CONSOLE, SQL_LOGIN, SQL_PASSWORD`

So if you use Windows Authentication, it would work, because you are not passing login and password, but instead of correct Database Name you are passing password, so your user ends up into `Master` db, which does not contain required table.

Comment: i did notice that after posting it but that don't change that you're a genius